# Formula Turning into Absolute Cell Reference Through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The code below should create a dynamic formula, however when it runs, the initial row for the sum is kept and leads to errors. Why is it doing this when the sum should show T4 without the $?

```
LastCol = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
.Range("S4:S" & .Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula _
= "=IF(R4="""","""",SUM(T4:" & .Cells(4, LastCol).Address & "))"
```

Here is the formula it creates:

```
=IF(R12="","",SUM(T$4:$CX12))
```

Comment: `Address` returns an absolute reference by default.

Comment: This is not the answer for the question . It is about the adding the `$` sign. Otherwise the created formulas different literally in the different cells, but this not affect the final result.